# how to use session inside UserDetailsService in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have a employee table with login details and a branch_id from branch table.after login i get the username,password,authorities from UserDetailsService.how to get the branch_id of the user.?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create an implementation of UserDetails which includes all fields you need?

If you are already creating a UserDetailsService, returning another type of UserDetails is so simple. Then it could be saved in the Authentication class you are using, maybe just saving it to details property.

Edit:

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails{

        private Object branchId; 

        /**
         * @return the branchId
         */
        public Object getBranchId() {
            return branchId;
        }

        /**
         * @param branchId the branchId to set
         */
        public void setBranchId(Object branchId) {
            this.branchId = branchId;
        }

        //@Override other methods

}
```

Then create an instance of that in your UserDetailsService implementing class

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String arg0)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        MyUserDetailsuserDetails = new MyUserDetails();
        ...
        userDetails.setBranchId(theBranchId);

        return userDetails;
    }
```

Comment: UserDetailsService interface is a default interface provided by spring security. i create an implementation class that implements  UserDetailsService and override the default method.

Comment: That's just what I mean. If you are creating your own implementation of a UserDetailsService, why don't make it return a UserDetails implementing class with all properties you need?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following listener to web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
 </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then add the following code to your userdetailsservice implementation class.

```
@Autowired  
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

After that, you can set session attribute inside the
`public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username){}` method.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("branchId", employeeVO.getBranch_id());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **UserDetailsService** implements **UserDetailsManager**, just use the **loadUserByUsername** method to load the data you need.

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
```

You can use @Autowired to get access on a datasource to fetch the data.

Comment: the loadUserByUsername method will return UserDetails. that contains username,password and authorities. cannot get the branch_id.

Comment: @Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

using the above code i create a session attribute and set the branch_id to that object.

Comment: If you implement UserDetails, you can store custom data, and then return it with **loadUserByUsername** (see @jlumietu answer). There is no need to set a new attribute to the session.